# How to update variable inputed in html form to javascript code until variable changed by user again

Tags: javascript, html

I am updating the radius of a circle through an html form I am drawing that bounces off walls. However, the circle is only drawn for what I assume is the length of time the function runs which is virtually nothing, then it disappears. How would I make the variable of the radius be equal to what the user inputs indefinitely until the user updates the variable by inputing another value in the html form.

I've tried defining the variable radius as such: 
var radius = document.querySelector('#mass').value;

with no function and it did not seem to work. Maybe it has to do something with the scope of the variable within the function as I am also defining the variable "circle" which provides the parameters for drawing the circle within the on-submit function. However I also already tried defining that outside the on-submit function.

```
<canvas> </canvas>

  <script>


        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

          var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
              ;
          canvas.width = 500;
          canvas.height = 500;
          console.log(canvas);

          var c = canvas.getContext('2d');


          function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.dx = dx;
            this.dy = dy;
            this.radius = radius;

            this.draw = function() {
              c.beginPath();
              c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2,
                false);
              c.strokeStyle = "black";
              c.stroke();
            }

            this.update = function() {
              if (this.x + this.radius > 500 || this.x - this.radius 
               < 0) {
                this.dx =- this.dx;

              }

              if (this.y + this.radius > 500 || this.y - this.radius 
              < 0) {
                this.dy =- this.dy
              }

              this.x += this.dx;
              this.y += this.dy;

              this.draw();
            }
          }


           document.querySelector('#form').onsubmit= function(){

            radius = document.querySelector('#mass').value;
            circle = new Circle(250, 100, 5, 5, radius);
          };

          function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            c.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

            circle.update();

          }

          animate();

        });


    </script>

    <div style="text-align:center">
        <form id="form" method="post">
            <input id="mass" type="number" name="mass" value="mass" 
             placeholder="mass"/>
            <button type="submit" class="w3-dark-gray w3- 
             button">Solve</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

My ultimate goal is for the circle animation to run after the radius has been defined by the user through the html form and for the circle to change in radius size when the user re inputs the form with a different value for the radius. However, at this point the circle is only drawn with the expected radius for a tiny instant as the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try on button click, runs for a bit before crashing.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {

          var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
              ;
          canvas.width = 500;
          canvas.height = 500;
          console.log(canvas);

          var c = canvas.getContext('2d');


          function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.dx = dx;
            this.dy = dy;
            this.radius = radius;

            this.draw = function() {
              c.beginPath();
              c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2,
                false);
              c.strokeStyle = "black";
              c.stroke();
            }

            this.update = function() {
              if (this.x + this.radius > 500 || this.x - this.radius 
               < 0) {
                this.dx =- this.dx;

              }

              if (this.y + this.radius > 500 || this.y - this.radius 
              < 0) {
                this.dy =- this.dy
              }

              this.x += this.dx;
              this.y += this.dy;

              this.draw();
            }
          }



            let radius = parseInt(document.querySelector('#mass').value);
            let circle = new Circle(250, 100, 5, 5, radius);


          function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            c.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

            circle.update();

          }

          animate();

        });
```

```html
<canvas> </canvas>


    <div style="text-align:center">
        <form id="form" method="post">
            <input id="mass" type="number" name="mass" value="mass" 
             placeholder="mass"/>
            <button id="btn" type="submit" class="w3-dark-gray w3- 
             button">Solve</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```